# Create one list with two ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a dynamically generated list for each item in my inventory using two API's. The part I am having a hard time figuring out is how to get the value from different calls, and merging them into the same list using a pk and fk.

The lists I am trying to create.

```
<ul>
 <li>id</li>
 <li>description</li>
 <li>quantity</li>
</ul>
```

Also, the Item doesn't have to have a quantity listed.

```
 function getItems(){
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
  url: 'item/item',
    success: function(response){
    var items = response.detail;
    html = '';
   for (var i=0;i < items.length; i++){
        html += '<ul>'
        html += '<li>' + items[i].id + '</li>'
        html += '<li>' + items[i].description + '</li>'
        html += '</ul>'
   }
 }
})
}
//The Inventory has a FK item_id to the ID in item.

    function getInventory(){
    $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'item/inventory',
    success: function(response){
        var inventory = response.detail;
      html = '';
      for (var j=0; j < inventory.length; j++){
           html += '<li>' + inventory[j].quantity + '</li>'
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to make 2 requests for this? I would load all the data on the server side then call the endpoint once though ajax.

Comment: That is actually what I am wanting to do, but I am being instructed to do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call one ajax in success of another.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

function getItems(){
    $.ajax({
       method: 'GET',
       url: 'item.php',
       success: function(response1)
       {
       var items = JSON.parse(response1);

       $.ajax({
     method: 'GET',
     url: 'inv.php',
     success: function(response2){
        var inventory = JSON.parse(response2);
        html = '';

           for (var i=0;i < items.length; i++)
           {
             html += '<ul>';
             html += '<li>' + items[i].id + '</li>';
             html += '<li>' + items[i].description + '</li>';
             html += '<li>' + inventory[i].quantity + '</li>';
             html += '</ul>';
           }

           $('body').append(html);
       }
        });
       }
     });
}

getItems();
});
```